# How to match a percentage regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm struggling checking if the my string is matching the percentage pattern, i.e. any non-space (or tab, new line) char repeat more than once, and at the end a percentage sign.

It should be easy, but I'm trying:

```
third_col="88.90%"
if [[ $third_col == '.+%' ]]; then
  echo "matches"
fi
```

And it doesn't output "matches". I wonder what part in the regex was wrong.

Comment: `[[ $third_col == *'%' ]]` should work

Comment: @anubhava yes! This is working. Can I ask why we need to quote the percentage sign?

Comment: @anubhava _"any non-space (or tab, new line) char repeat more than once, and at the end a percentage sign"_ I would say that's not possible with standard globing?

Comment: @Fravadona: [With extended globbing it is doable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70664510/548225)

Comment: The `==` operator does not accept regular expressions. You want `==` (or more correctly `=`) with a glob pattern, or `=~` with an actual regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> any non-space (or tab, new line) char repeat more than once, and at the end a percentage sign

Here is a non-regex way using `extglob`:

```
+([![:blank:]])%
```

Which matches 1 or more of non-blank character followed by a `%`.

**Code:**

```sh
for s in '88.90%' '81.4' '5 1%' '%15' ' %' 'abc%'; do
    [[ $s == +([![:blank:]])% ]] && echo "'$s' ok" || echo "'$s' no"
done

'88.90%' ok
'81.4' no
'5 1%' no
'%15' no
' %' no
'abc%' ok
```

Thanks to comments below. If you are on bash version < 4.1 then enable `extglob` before running this script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` may be needed; In macOS/FreeBSD/Solaris, `extglob` is turned off by default.

Comment: @Fravadona: Inside `[[ ... ]]` extended globbing is enabled by default

Comment: extglob inside `[[` seems to be the specified behaviour since bash 4.1 (according to [NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS#n936)).

Comment: @rowboat True, but it fails on macOS bash 3.2 when the extglob is not expanded from a variable

Comment: Thanks guys, I have made a note in my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match any one or more non-whitespace chars and a `%` at the end, you need to use a *regex* (enabled with `=~` operator), not a glob pattern (`==` uses glob pattern matching), and the pattern should be something like `^[^[:space:]]+%$`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
third_col="88.90%"
rx='^[^[:space:]]+%$'
if [[ "$third_col" =~ $rx ]]; then
  echo "matches"
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Dj5PCf). Here, `[^[:space:]]+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars.

A bit more precise pattern will be

```sh
rx='^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?%$'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/IpkPjJ). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `%` - a `%` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

A standard `case` statement can do that:

```
third_col=88.90%

case $third_col in
  *[[:space:]]*) ;;
  ?*%) echo matches ;;
esac
```

If there are any spaces in `$third_col`, do nothing. Otherwise, if it ends with "%", `echo matches`.

You can expand on the first pattern to reject other invalid cases, for example:

```
third_col=88.90%

case $third_col in
  *[!%.0123456789]* | *%*%* | *.*.*) ;;
  ?*%) echo matches ;;
esac
```